# How to fix "server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of 'image/jpeg'" error?

Tags: javascript, mime, parceljs

Recently deployed new site to github pages with parceljs and I'm getting this error for every image:

Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "image/jpeg". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

```
import meditatingImage from "../imgs/meditate.jpg";
```

Is this saying that MIME type of jpeg can't be used within my JS?

repo: github.com/joshromanrogers/notflix

Comment: Need more context. What are you serving exactly? Show the code. And what are the headers you are setting while sending the response?

Comment: I've added an example of one of the images that is causing the issue. Do I have to import the images from the dist file that is produced when I bundle with parceljs?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I don't, would using that make the JPGs importable from a bundle?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan but I'm using ParcelJS not RollupJS

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan do you think this could do the trick? https://github.com/fansenze/parcel-plugin-url-loader

Comment: I don't think so because assets should be supported by default and this specific plugin just extends default behavior, I think it will be easier if you just show your code repo instead of us trying to guess. With regards to error message itself seems the code is executed in a native module script which requires every import to have a script mime type, which infers that somehow parcel didn't process the imports at all. So just share the code let's have a look.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan https://github.com/joshromanrogers/notflix Thanks!